# Android как принять массив во втором активити

Tags: java, android

Ребят такой вопрос, получил через ретрофит данные в список, список передаю во второй активити, всё принимается хорошо через гетеры, а вот массив не получается, подскажите как сделать.

Второе активити

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    capital_view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.capital_id);
    language_view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.languages_id);
    timezone_view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timezones_id);
    population_view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.population_id);

    Countrys countrys = (Countrys) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("key");



    capital_view.setText("Capital : " + countrys.getCapital());
    population_view.setText("Population : " + countrys.getPopulation());
    language_view.setText(countrys.getLanguages());// вот тут не принимает



}
```

}

В классе

```
String[] languages;



public String[] getLanguages() {
    return languages;
}

public void setLanguages(String[] languages) {
    this.languages = languages;
}
```

Интент

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                    Countrys countrys = countries.get(position);
                    mIntent.putExtra("key", countrys);
                    startActivity(mIntent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле у Вас всё передается. Нельзя просто так взять и вставить массив в `textView` =)
исправьте на

```
language_view.setText(Arrays.toString(countrys.getLanguages()).replaceAll("\\[|\\]", ""));
```

Comment: Только на replaceAll ругается, там что- то со скобками не то, а так помогло, спасибо!)

Comment: Можно убрать) Незачто

Answer (score 1):

Вы для приема параметра делаете getSerializable(). Ваш класс Countrys должен выглядеть так:

```
public class Adress implements Serializable{
     //Тело класса
}
```

Comment: Страну и население я не получил бы без этого, а у меня с ними все в порядке, но всё равно спасибо)